# Play sound on remote server when a user visits a certain webpage

Tags: audio, asp-classic, playback

I've to play a sound on the server machine when I access on certain page with a client machine.

Is that possible with classic ASP?

Comment: Which OS is your IIS server hosted on..?

Comment: have you found an alternative way to approach this..? Could you share the same below? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASP being just a scripting language doesn't offer any facility to directly play a sound clip.
But we can use the `CreateObject` function to create a command shell instance and run sndrec32 (Sound recorder available in Win XP) and pass the .WAV sound file's path as an argument to it between double quotes.

Create a module file: functions.asp

```
Option Explicit

Dim strSoundFile, objShell, strCommand

Sub PlaySound()
    strSoundFile = "C:\Path\of\some\file.wav"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strCommand = "sndrec32 /play /close " & chr(34) & strSoundFile & chr(34)
    objShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
End Sub
```

In your ASP code, enter the following code at the beginning of the page where you want to make the call:

```
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->

PlaySound
```

**Reference:** 
[How-can-i-play-a-sound-from-within-a-script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/03/how-can-i-play-a-sound-from-within-a-script.aspx)

Comment: Nice, long ago I wrote classic ASP code that caused a beep on the server when there was an error. This is so much better! ;)

Comment: Haha.. well I won't try that else the beeps won't stop after one of my marathon coding sessions :P